# i need a batch script to open a file in ANSI encoding with notepad and Save As "somename.txt"

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file with `UTF-8` encodding and now i want to convert that file to `ANSI` encodding.

I tried opening a text file in notepad with `ANSI` encodding and tried copied to another file so that the another file will be having the same contents with `ANSI` encodding.

```
%SystemRoot%\notepad.exe /a "output1.txt" >> output2.txt
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need notepad for this. In fact, notepad is a really poor choice for encoding conversion. The widely used tool for encoding conversion is `iconv`. You can get ready to use binaries by installing *[MSys2](https://www.msys2.org/)*.

Another option is to use – say – Python3 for conversion

```
open(out_file_name, 'w', encoding=out_encoding).write(open(in_file_name, 'r', encoding=in_encoding).read())
```